# (Absolute) convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We want to check if the following series converges (absolutely).

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

This is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k}{\sqrt{k+1}}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}{\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1+\sqrt{k^2+k}}
\end{align}

But how do we continue from here?

Comment: I think you're missing absolute value signs. Though it wouldn't make a difference in your case since your terms are nonnegative for every $k$.

Comment: Try limit comparison test with $a_k=\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ and $b_k=\frac{1}{k}$

Comment: Hint: $\,\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k} \lt 2 \sqrt{k+1}\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{1}{k+1+\sqrt{k^2+k}} > \frac{1}{k+1+\sqrt{k^2+2k+1}} = \frac{1}{2(k+1)} .$$
Thus the comparison test shows that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ diverges.

Comment: very well put solution!

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\forall k \in \Bbb N,\quad \sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} = \sqrt{k+1}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k+1}}\right)
$$
and since $\sqrt{1+x} \underset{x\to 0}{=} 1 +\frac{1}{2}x + o(x)$, it follows that the general term in the summation satisfies
$$
\frac{\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}} \underset{k\to\infty}{=} \frac{1}{2(k+1)} + o\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right).
$$
The general term in the summation is thus equivalent to $\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$, from which we deduce that the sum is divergent.

Comment: How do you get to $(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k+1}}$?

Comment: I would say it's the general trick "$0 = 1-1$" : Factor by $\sqrt{k+1}$ and write $\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}} = \sqrt{\frac{k+1-1}{k+1}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k+1}}$.

Answer (score 3):

> \begin{align}
> S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k}{\sqrt{k+1}}
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k)(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}{\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k)}\\
> &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1+\sqrt{k^2+k}}
> \end{align}

Next, we have:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k+1+\sqrt{k^2+k}}>\frac{1}{k+k+\sqrt{k^2+k^2}}=\frac{1}{2k+\sqrt{2}k}>\frac{1}{4k}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
S>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4k}
\end{align}

So, it is divergent.